# Does native vlan tagging work with voice vlan?

Tags: vlan, spanning-tree

we hard-code native vlan tagging:

```
vlan dot1q tag native
```

then we configure a port like this:

```
interface FastEthernet0/1
switchport access vlan 20
switchport mode access
switchport voice vlan 500
mls qos trust cos
spanning-tree portfast
```

Does this cause problem? I mean second configuration assumes that there are two vlans:

1. native vlan which is untagged (but here it is tagged)
2. voice vlan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked this question in [networking-forum](http://www.networking-forum.com/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=28487&p=192764) and they told:

> No, the IOS doesn't consider the voice/access port a trunk port.